# Mimicking a join and group by statement with multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

## Source/Input

I have a multidimensional array:

```
array (size=2)
  'array_one' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
          1 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
      'myid' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
          1 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
  'array_two' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'DEF' (length=3)
          1 => string 'DEF' (length=3)
      'myid' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'DEF' (length=3)
          1 => string 'DEF' (length=3)
```

i want to combine the arrays but if an array element's key is the same i want to replace both element with a new element with a new (dynamically created using it's parent) name, i want the output to look something like this:

## Expected Output

```
array (size=1)
  'new_array' => 
    array (size=2)
      'myid_array_one' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
          1 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
      'myid_array_two' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'DEF' (length=3)
          1 => string 'DEF' (length=3)
```

## Method

This is what i have tried:

```
public function data_combine($data_set_arrays) {
    $result = [];
    $accociative = $data_set_arrays;
    foreach($accociative as &$array) {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if(is_int($key)) {
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($accociative as $array) {
        //make sure no elements have same name
        $parent = key($array);
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $duplicates = array_intersect_key($data_set_arrays, $array); {
                foreach($duplicates as $key => $value) {
                    $array[$key.'_'.$parent] = $array[$key];
                    unset($array[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        $result = array_merge_recursive($result, $array);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

but i can't see the wood for the trees, can someone lend a hand?

Comment: To the person you marked this as unclear - please can you explain why this is unclear (forgive the irony). The title 'Source' and 'Expected Output' surely indicates i want to change 'this' into 'that' doesn't it?